# What are the downsides of using the hidden _stop() function to kill a thread?

Tags: python, thread-safety, python-multithreading

While searching for a way to quickly kill a thread when using Python's out-of-the-box threading module, I came across this method: [Use the Hidden `_stop()` Function to Kill a Thread in Python](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-kill-thread/#use-the-hidden-stop-function-to-kill-a-thread-in-python)

There is presumably a reason behind why the `_stop()` function is protected rather than public. My assumption is that it's to make it difficult to terminate a thread unsafely, but I'm curious about whether there are any other reasons.

What are the downsides to calling `_stop()` to kill a thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you linked to doesn't call the private `._stop()` function at all. Instead the constructor replaces it entirely with an `Event`:

```
        self._stop = threading.Event()
```

That appears senseless to me.

The actual private `._stop()` function does **NOT** stop a thread. There is nothing in `threading.py` that can do so. Instead the private `._stop()` function is called internally to maintain Python-level module invariants after the C implementation has determined that a thread's life *has* (already) ended. There is no case in which it would make sense for user-level code to call it.

EDIT: by the way, in the current Python (>= 3.10), calling `._stop()` on a thread that's alive just dies at once with an `AssertionError`, and that's its only effect. As I recall, in some older Python versions `._stop()` went on to corrupt some of `threading.py`'s internals (destroyed its knowledge of which threads were actually still alive). In no case, though, did it ever stop the thread.